# XSLT conditional template match on two attributes

Tags: xslt, svg

I have to parse this SVG and apply some transformations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="540pt" height="263pt" viewBox="0 0 540 263" version="1.1">
    <g id="surface1">
        ...
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270 67.160156 L 270.238281 67.640625 L 277.679688 67.640625 "/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270.238281 67.640625 L 271.199219 68.839844 L 285.359375 68.839844 "/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270.238281 67.640625 L 277.679688 67.640625 L 285.359375 68.839844 "/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 271.199219 68.839844 L 272.878906 71.238281 L 293.039062 71.238281 "/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 271.199219 68.839844 L 285.359375 68.839844 L 293.039062 71.238281 "/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 272.878906 71.238281 L 275.28125 74.601562 L 300 74.601562 "/>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

I need a template that matches the `path` elements where the `style` attribute contains the string `fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)` and the `d` attribute contains two times the letter `L`. Here is what I got:

```
<xsl:template match="@style[contains(., 'fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)')] and @d[string-length() - string-length(translate(., 'L', '')) = 2]">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

It seems that each condition alone works, but when together, it doesn't.

```
<xsl:template match="@style[contains(., 'fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="@d[string-length() - string-length(translate(., 'L', '')) = 2]">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, a match on the `path` element doesn't seem to work...

```
<xsl:template match="path">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full transformation file. The problem seems to be the match on the `path` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="stroke">black</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="stroke-width">50px</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text()|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="path[@style[contains(., 'fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)')] and @d[string-length() - string-length(translate(., 'L', '')) = 2]]">
        <xsl:attribute name="d">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected result should be (notice the letter `Z` appended to the `d` attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="540pt" height="263pt" viewBox="0 0 540 263" version="1.1">
    <g id="surface1">
        ...
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270 67.160156 L 270.238281 67.640625 L 277.679688 67.640625 Z"/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270.238281 67.640625 L 271.199219 68.839844 L 285.359375 68.839844 Z"/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 270.238281 67.640625 L 277.679688 67.640625 L 285.359375 68.839844 Z"/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 271.199219 68.839844 L 272.878906 71.238281 L 293.039062 71.238281 Z"/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 271.199219 68.839844 L 285.359375 68.839844 L 293.039062 71.238281 Z"/>
        <path style=" stroke:black;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 272.878906 71.238281 L 275.28125 74.601562 L 300 74.601562 Z"/>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have got is with namespaces. The elements in your XML input are part of a namespace

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

This means you need to reference that namespace in your XSLT too....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Then you use this prefix in a template match

```
<xsl:template match="svg:path">
```

Now, you actually want to match the `d` attribute here, so your template would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="svg:path[contains(@style, 'fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)')]
     /@d[string-length() - string-length(translate(., 'L', '')) = 2]">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: All I want to achieve, is to add the letter `Z` to the `d` attribute of the paths that fit both conditions.

Comment: I edited the post with the correct condition (see last block of code). But still, the `path` element is never matched.

Comment: I've amended the answer to show this. Don't forget to say what you need in your question! (Showing your expected output in your question would also help). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it still doesn't match the `path` element. See: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c0fa77374d1c9d16dcba6011a79a341e and http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/251baf7a2a8794d0ae1691ffa54501e3 In this test, it works without the `path` element, but as I understand, we need to specify it in order to do multiple conditions.

Comment: Ah! The issue is actually with namespaces. I will edit my answer to explain.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include about namespaces, and also show (hopefully) the correct template use!

Answer (score 3):

> All I want to achieve, is to add the letter Z to the d attribute of
>   the paths that fit both conditions.

Then your template should match either the `@d` attribute or its parent `path` element - not its sibling `@style` attribute, the way you have it now (not to mention that your syntax is invalid).

Try it this way, perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="@d[string-length() - string-length(translate(., 'L', '')) = 2] [contains(../@style, 'fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%)')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```